# Plot 3d vectors and points on the same plot in python?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot, vector

I have the following matrix:

```
 X = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]])
```

and the following vectors

```
Vecs = np.array([[ 0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ],
       [ 0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ],
       [-0.70710678,  0.70710678,  0.        ]])
```

I want to draw the vectors `vecs[:,0]`, `vecs[:,1]`, `vecs[:,2]` (the rows of the matrix) on the same plot as the points [1,3,5] and [2,4,6]. The vectors should be orthogonal if possible to draw a 90 degree label but its not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `scatter` for points and `quiver` for vectors + experiment with different parameters of `view_init` to find the best angle:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ax.view_init(15, 35)
ax.scatter(xs=X[0], ys=X[1], zs=X[2], color='crimson')
ax.quiver(0, 0, 0, Vecs[:,0], Vecs[:,1], Vecs[:,2], color='steelblue')
```

Output:

[image: picture]